# keycode center button samsung galaxy s

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode, samsung-mobile

I´m tryning to capture event of the front key´s Samsung galaxsy S but i don´t know the correct code, I check this:

```
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)    
                {
                    todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

too with `KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER` but no capture the centre button

anyone know the keycode for this button?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you **can't** catch whether the home button was pressed .Using KeyCodes doesn't seem to work for HOME Android has kept the functionality of home button separate from other keys. The preferred way is to deal with onStop() of your Activity being called when the user presses HOME.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
    super.onStop();
//put your logic here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I'm aware of for the Home Button is

Activity.onUserLeaveHint()

Best regards.